# CSS float and clear not giving the right results

Tags: html, css

[image]
If you look at the screenshot, i need the 'title', 'subtitle' and 'social media icons' on the same line , so i float the 'title' to left and float the 'social media icons' to right because i want them to be on the extreme right end, but when i give it a float of right, it spoils the alignment of the navigation menu ( circled red ) which is supposed to be below and takes it to the top. Any solutions for this?
The following is my html5 code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <link href = "css/style.css" rel = "stylesheet" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "container">
        <header>
            <div id = "title">Test title</div>
            <div id = "subtitle">test subtitle</div>
            <div id = "socialmedia">
                <ul id = "socialicons">
                    <li>facebook</li>
                    <li>twitter</li>
                    <li>linkedin</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul id = "mainmenu">
                <li>About Me</li>
                <li>My Portfolio</li>
                <li>Services Offered</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this the css code

```
#header{
height: 1000px;
}
#title{
float: left;
padding: 10px;
}
#subtitle{
float: left;
padding: 10px;
}
#socialicons{
padding: 10px;
float: right;
}
#socialicons li{
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
}
#mainmenu li{
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: When you float something, you take it out of the normal document flow. This means that any code/markup that comes after the floated element will move up. Try putting the floated elements in a container div and then make sure that the container div doesn't collapse. [All About CSS Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `header` contains only floated elements. Its `height` is `0px`. The `nav` is just under this 0px header.

So, two ways to solve this :

1/ giving a fixed height to your header.

2/ using a clearfix. The best one is this [micro-clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

```
cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Just add a `.cf` class to your `header`, it'll do the work.

Comment: Giving a fixed height to the header worked ! Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution to your problem.

Try to keep your css simple and clean. Use classes or id`s like left and right

Example:

```
 #left{float: left;}
 #right {float:right;}
```

Solution to your problem: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7K64m/)

Comment: Also, i recommend you to use CSS Frameworks: Zurb Foundation or Bootstrap. They will make your life easy.

Comment: What does `display: inline-block` do for the floated block? Doesn't `float: left` imply `display: block` (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)?

Comment: My mistake, forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution based on what you provided:

```
// Add padding to the mainmenu
#mainmenu {
  padding: 10px;
}

// Remove the margin on socialicons
#socialicons {
  margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ey3jx/

Navigation below:

```
#mainmenu {
  /* other rules */
  clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ey3jx/2/

Comment: Your jsfiddle code aligns everything on one line... but i want the navigation below.. anyways thanks for the help !

Comment: I've updated the answer. Add `clear: both` to the `mainmenu` and it should push it down a line.

Comment: Now its proper..! Thanks for the help !